# Banner slider storing slides in js object vs li elements

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow, banner

I am developing a simple banner slider. I have three options how to store slide elements:

a) I can store banner slides inside javascript object and then create slides li elements with jquery.

```
bannerSlides = {
  "1":{
    "bannerId":"1",
    "title":"Some title 1",
    "content":"<p><h2>Some title 1<\/h2><img src=\"http:\/\/www.domain.com\/media\/wysiwyg\/Sea.jpg\" alt=\"\" \/><\/p>",
    "anotherparameter":"paramvalue",
    "anotherparameter2":"paramvalue"
  },
  "2":{
    "bannerId":"2",
    "title":"Some title 2",
    "content":"<p><h2>Some title 2<\/h2><img src=\"http:\/\/www.domain.com\/media\/wysiwyg\/Sun.jpg\" alt=\"\" \/><\/p>",
    "anotherparameter":"paramvalue",
    "anotherparameter2":"paramvalue"
  },
  "3":{
    "bannerId":"3",
    "title":"Some title 3",
    "content":"<p><h2>Some title 3<\/h2><img src=\"http:\/\/www.domain.com\/media\/wysiwyg\/Summer.jpg\" alt=\"\" \/><\/p>",
    "anotherparameter":"paramvalue",
    "anotherparameter2":"paramvalue"
  }  
};
```

b) I can display banner slides directly as list elements inside ul like this:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;">
  <ul style="width: 300%; position: relative; left: -100%; height: 350px;">
    <li style="width: 33.3333%;">Slide 1</li>
    <li style="width: 33.3333%;">Slide 2</li>
    <li style="width: 33.3333%;">Slide 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

c) Display only first slide directly as li element to display it instantly, the rest of li elements inject with javascript.

I checked amazon site and I can see they use c) option. I am not sure why a) is not ok. What option would be the best from SEO and other point of view?

Answer (score 0):

Option C is a trade off between speed and flexibility. The first slide can be displayed without waiting for any scripts to load, but doesn't come with the overhead of loading all the images at once as may be the case with option B. From a SEO point of with option A hides all your data from search engines that not searching inside your script files. If SEO is a major concern go with B or C. If initial page load time is most important go for A or C.